# VirtualBox broke Fedora networking - how to fix it?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, linux-kernel, fedora-21

I was trying to install VirtualBox in my Fedora 21 machine. However, the cited machine has Secure Boot enabled and obviously VirtualBox startup failed miserably due to lack of signing in its modules. It instantly broke systemd-modules-load due to lack of signing key, so I uninstalled anything which could possibly be causing trouble.

However, my networking is still broken. It seems VirtualBox installation messed my network interfaces. I just discovered I can successfully use my network interfaces in the previous kernel version I have installed, but can't manage to make them work in the current version. Also, it seems the current kernel version is not installed, because `rpm -q kernel` doesn't list it.

Any tips or tricks on how could I get everything working fine again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to know exactly what VirtualBox did (especially without the details of how you uninstalled it), but since you say that the older kernel is working fine, I think the following is highly likely to be a successful approach to repair:

1. Boot into older kernel
2. Make sure that the newest kernel is not installed. (`yum remove` if necessary.)
3. Now, `yum upgrade`, which will pull in and reinstall that newer kernel.
4. Reboot into the new kernel again; odds are good it will work.

If not, I bet VirtualBox isn't really completely installed, so I'd start working from there.)

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I was able to make it work again, but unfortunately will have to look for some alternative to VirtualBox.

Comment: @Mauren The built-in KVM virtualization technology should cover most use cases. Try GNOME Boxes for a simple UI or Virt Manager for a more advanced one.